# FinanceKit - Authorization process is not entitled error

Tags: ios, swift, wallet

I'm currently experimenting with the latest Xcode beta 15.3 (15E5194e) and attempting to integrate [FinanceKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/financekit) into my project. However, I've encountered a persistent issue where the app crashes upon attempting to read or request authorization, accompanied by the following error message:

`FinanceKit/FinanceStore+FinancialDataAuthorization.swift:52: Fatal error: Process is not entitled`

Upon investigation, I've found no evident entitlements for FinanceKit, despite exploring options like Apple Wallet. Furthermore, I thoroughly examined the info.plist for relevant privacy values but found nothing pertinent.

Here's the code snippet that triggers the fatal error, whether it's the request or read function:

```swift
import FinanceKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        requestFinancePermission()
        // readFinancePermission()
    }
    
    private func requestFinancePermission() {
        Task {
            do {
                let status = try await FinanceStore.shared.requestAuthorization()
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func readFinancePermission() {
        Task {
            do {
                let status = try await FinanceStore.shared.authorizationStatus()
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the API is available on Xcode 15.3b, the capabilities are not yet turned on for everyone.
I believe you will have to go to your app configuration in the developer portal under capabilities & app services.

Comment: Based on the response [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/746770). This doesn't appear to be correct. Additionally, I don't see the capability for FinanceKit that you're referring to.